# Android TabHost destroys activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a tabhost with 3 tabs in it. On tabpress a specific activity is loaded via intent.
Each activity has a timer in a thread.

So the problem is that when I choose a different tab, the previous destroys and therefore the timer stops as well.

I would like to have all 3 activities to run in parallel without destroying. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

When you switch tabs, the last Activity loses the foreground and `onPause()` and `onStop()` get called just like every other Activity that loses the foreground. You could try extending the application class and keep your timer in there or creating some sort of static globals class.  Otherwise you could try using views instead of activities to display your content, and then your timer will stay active since that activity will always have the foreground while your application is being used.